# IE8 Accelerators

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Does anyone know of any useful Accelerators for IE8?

I have to use IE8 at work sometimes and I noticed this feature, but I couldn't think of any real application of it other than search.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [here](http://www.ieaddons.com/en/accelerators/).

Answer (score 1):

1. Map on Live Maps – One of the default Internet Explorer 8 accelerators that comes preinstalled. It can be used to quickly lookup an address on Live Maps.
2. Find On eBay – Will look up the selected text on eBay displaying matching auctions.
3. Translate With Live Search – Another default Internet Explorer 8 Accelerator that can quickly translate selected text in the web browser.
4. Weather.com – Look up weather information at weather.com.
5. Wikipedia Accelerator – Makes it possible to quickly look up information at the online encyclopedia Wikipedia.
6. Look up in Google News – Will look up the selected text in Google News.
7. Sent with Windows Live Hotmail – send selected information with an Windows Live Hotmail account.
8. Login Using BugmeNot – BugMeNot is a service that operates a database of public login credentials that can be used log into websites without registration.
9. Blogger – The Blogger Accelerator makes it easier to write about interesting stories discovered on the Internet.
10. Share With delicious – Share information easier with Delicious.

Comment: source :http://www.ghacks.net/2009/02/25/10-useful-internet-explorer-8-accelerators/

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite is Preview and Launch URL.  Great for URLs the page author didn't make a hyperlink and the one feature of Opera I wish the other browsers would take up.